# print alias to txt file

Tags: command-line

let's say I create alias x that says something when x is written to terminal:

alias x='echo yyyyyyyyy'

Now I want to  x.txt file that prints my alias x. How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this a school task?

Comment: No. Why did you ask?

Comment: Because it looks like one. Can you explain why you need this? ;-)

Comment: Teaching myself how to use terminal. Found materials on the web.  Couldn't get an answer to this one. I'm still a noob

Answer (score 2):

The `alias` shell builtin is used both to define *and* to display aliases. So

```
alias x > x.txt
```

will output the definition of alias `x` and redirect it to file `x.txt`